# Working with grunt serve and apache to prevent crossdomain error

Tags: apache, gruntjs, yeoman

Okay, I've been struggling on development because of this cross domain restriction on my php-angular application development.

I am using yeoman to scaffold my application thus it has a `grunt` task of server which opens an http server at port `9001`

Now I have created a `REST`-like api in php as my backend to provide service to my angularjs application.

During development I always create a dummy data in instead of using that `api` I made because I cannot make those two separate things together, then after I am finish building the front end, I will `build` it and copy to the folder of the api, so I can now test it to work together, which is really not so efficient and fast for development.

Now I came across this [article](http://alfrescoblog.com/2014/06/14/angular-js-activiti-webapp-with-activiti-rest/#)

That taught how to make those two work together, but I think I failed to understand and failed to do it properly.

Here is my configuration for a `site-available` in apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.dev
  ServerALias www.foo.dev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/foo
  ProxyPass /api/ http://foo.dev/api/ retry=0 timeout=30 
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:9001/ retry=0 timeout=30
  <Directory "/var/www/html/foo">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What happens now, is that `http://foo.dev` now works, just like what I see in `localhost:9001`, but it cannot access `http://foo.dev/api`

What is wrong in my setup. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you backend has created with PHP, you will need create a .htaccess file in the root directory of you PHP.

Set this:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type"
</ifModule>
```